# Android Directions API ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, api, directions

I am using the Google Directions API. Everything works well until I set the TravelMode to BICYCLING. 
All other modes work until this attribute is set.

The error I get is: `onFailure: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0`

Why am I getting this error?

Here is the code:

```
    private void calculateDirections(Marker marker){
        Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: calculating directions.");

        com.google.maps.model.LatLng destination = new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(
                marker.getPosition().latitude,
                marker.getPosition().longitude
        );
        DirectionsApiRequest directions = new DirectionsApiRequest(mGeoApiContext);
        directions  .alternatives(true)
                    .origin(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(
                        deviceLocation.getLatitude(),
                        deviceLocation.getLongitude()));


        // Set imperial and transport mode
        try {
            if (imperial) {
                directions.units(Unit.IMPERIAL);
                Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: imperial set true");
            }
            switch (transportMode){
                case "Drive":
                    directions.mode(TravelMode.DRIVING);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: travelMode: " + transportMode);
                    break;
                case "Walk":
                    directions.mode(TravelMode.WALKING);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: travelMode: " + transportMode);
                    break;
                case "Transit":
                    directions.mode(TravelMode.TRANSIT);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: travelMode: " + transportMode);
                    break;
                case "Cycle":
                    directions.mode(TravelMode.BICYCLING);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: travelMode: " + transportMode);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "calculateDirections: imperial error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: destination: " + destination.toString());
        directions.destination(destination).setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: onResult: routes: " + result.routes[0].toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: onResult: duration: " + result.routes[0].legs[0].duration);
                Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: onResult: distance: " + result.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
                Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: onResult: geocodedWayPoints: " + result.geocodedWaypoints[0].toString());

                addPolyLinesToMap(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "calculateDirections: onFailure: " + e ); 

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely caused by there is no route for that travel mode (according to Google Direction Api). You have to check if `result.routes` is null or not before using it.

```
public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
         if (result.routes!=null&&result.routes.length>0){
             //draw polylines
         } else{
             //no route found
         }
}
```